# Discord Py - Is there anyways to add members to a private channel through discord py without the use of roles?

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there anyways to add members to a private channel through discord py without the use of roles. I understand that you could use roles in order to add user into the private channel by giving the user the speicfic role set that allows the user to access the channel. However, if i allow a mass amount of users to create their own specific private channels and assign them all with their own specific roles then the server roles would just be filled with rubbish spammed roles. I did thought of a timed role remover which tracks user activity in that channel, but that would be super host side reliant as this would bring alot of unnecessary packages thats been sent between host and servers.

I also tried to do invites which creates a invite link that would be sent to the user through dms when their channel has been created, but again the issue is ive set permission in which default roles do not have permission to view that channel, so therefore were back at the beginning again as it would require roles to view the channel.
Here is the code:

```py
category_name = "Pets_Private_Channels"
await ctx.send("Setting up management!")
category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=category_name)
user = ctx.author.id
overwrites = {
    ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False), #Make default not able to view this private channel
    ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True), #Add the bot to the channel
}


if category is None: #If there's no category matching with the `name`
    category = await ctx.guild.create_category(category_name, overwrites=None, reason=None)
    channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(user, overwrites=overwrites, reason=None, category=category)
    invitelink = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
    print(channel)
    await ctx.author.send(invitelink)

else: #Else if it found the categoty
    #await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(user, overwrites=overwrites, reason=None, category=category)
    channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(user, overwrites=overwrites, reason=None, category=category)
    invitelink = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
    print(channel)
    await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```

So im just wondering if there is anyway to add user to a channel without giving them the specific roles that they would need. Like how private channels you can "Add member or roles" We can just add a member.

Much appreciated if anyone could help with this. Thanks in advance.

***Issue was solved with this block of code.***

```
overwrites = {
         ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
         ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
         ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to specifically choose members in your overwrites. They must be of `discord.Member` object though.

```py
overwrites = {
             ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
             ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
             ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True), 
}
```

You can add as many `discord.Member` objects and put what you need.

Comment: Ohh wait what... I literally tried ctx.author yesterday but it showed an error related to attributes... Ohh wow idk what happened today but much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I think it might have been because you used `ctx.author.id`. I'm just assuming based on the `user` variable you used.

Comment: Ohh nonono i did use that at first but then changed it to ctx.author later on then just deleted it at the end because the attribute issue kept coming up... i have no idea @.@ but ayy it works now. Much appreciated again! great help thank you i was stuck on this for a laughable amount of time.